# Is there any support of IntelliJ IDEA for Apache Spark?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, apache-spark

I couldn't find anything around, so, is there any plugin for IntelliJ IDEA for Apache Spark? Some tools for running Spark applications, integration of the  Spark REPL and similar stuff from inside IDEA?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't really need any plugin, you can run it normally if you [set it up correctly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no standard plugin for `Apache Spark` in IntelliJ IEDA. Since IntelliJ IEDA is to write `Java` or `Scala`. If you choose `Java` to write your spark app, you can use `maven` easily. For `Scala`, I recommend `SBT` for building project.